# cron job not executing youtube-dl command

Tags: cron, youtube

I want to use the "youtube-dl" command in a cron job to download videos fron youtube. Therefore I created the following cron job:

```
26 00 * * * /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o '/home/ubuntu/youtube/%(title)s.%(ext)s' http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbbPU9KV1D2B4woNNQp3bWSotlHVVtRZr
```

When I run this command from the terminal, it works without problem, but if its called from the cron job it does not download anything. I've installed it via `apt-get install youtube-dl`.

`which youtube-dl` returns `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`

Best

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by making a bash script with the following contents.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -xwik -r 1M http://video.kings.nhl.com/videocenter/ -o '/data/www/kv/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s' >> /data/www/kv/out.txt
```

I tried a bunch of other stuff and the `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` ended up making it work.  It might also make the cron line work without the script as well, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The `%` character in the crontab command field is special.  You need to escape each one with a `\` character.

From `crontab(5)`:

```
The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be
run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or a
"%" character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified
in the SHELL variable of the cronfile.  A "%" character in the
command, unless escaped with a backslash (\), will be changed into
newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to
the command as standard input.
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your crontab entry to this

```
26 00 * * * /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o '/home/ubuntu/youtube/%(title)s.%(ext)s' http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbbPU9KV1D2B4woNNQp3bWSotlHVVtRZr > /home/ubuntu/youtube/Log 2>&1
```

You will even get to see the activity log in the `/home/ubuntu/youtube/Log` file.

Edit: Original code was trying to execute string constant. Ampersand in the end was redundant as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Didn't work and no Log file was created.

Comment: Do you have the folder `/home/ubuntu/youtube` created?

Comment: of course yes :)

Comment: You need to restart the cron after altering it. Did you do that as well?

Comment: I did it as well

Comment: Can you please post your crontab entry now? I would like to check, if something got missed...